# how to refresh firebase token from back-end using node.js

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, access-token

I need to know that if that possible to refresh the firebase access token from back-end using node.js. I can get the token from front end and I need to refresh it and verify if the token is expired.

condition : if the token expired then need to refresh it in the back-end. but the token is generating from front end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the **Refresh Token** to get a new ID Token (Access Token). If you are using the Firebase Auth Client SDK, then it'll do all of this.

```
// This returns existing token if valid 
// else it'll refresh the token and return an new one
const token = await auth.currentUser.getIdToken()
```

In case you still need to get new token in your backend server, then you can use [Firebase Auth REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-refresh-token).

Again, you'll need to store the refresh token in a secure place and I won't recommend doing this unless it's just for testing or you don't have any other way.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer! I also want to refresh the ID token on server e.g. to forward to login page if there isn't a valid one. right now my issue is that auth.verifyIdToken fails when the ID isn't valid anymore even though it would get refreshed immediately on the client with user.getIdToken. is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: @flair how are you generating the token at first place and why are you refreshing tokens on server? Can you please post a new question including the code used to get id token and other relevant details?

Comment: done, thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75365962/refresh-firebase-id-token-server-side

Comment: as my question is still unanswered, could I ask you to take a loot? Your help would be greatly appreciated! @Dharmaraj