# refresh firebase id token server-side

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js, firebase-authentication

I am working on an app with Next.js 13 and firebase auth with id tokens.

I want to leverage Next.JS built-in capability for server-side components to fetch user data faster, therefore I need to verify id tokens on the server at initial request. When no user is logged in on protected routes, I want to redirect to login page.

The problem arises when the user was inactive for >1h and the id token has expired. The next request header will send the expired token causing `auth.verifyIdToken` to reject it. This will redirect the user to login page, before any client-side code had a chance to run, including `user.getIdToken` to refresh the token.

**Is there a way to refresh the id token on server-side? I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73686177/how-to-refresh-firebase-token-from-back-end-using-node-js/73686213?noredirect=1#comment132982792_73686213), that there is a work-around using firebase REST API, which seems insecure.**

### Context

I use the `firebaseui` [package][2] for login, which creates the initial id token & refresh token. Then I have an `AuthContextProvider` to provide & refresh the id token on the client:

```js
const ServerAuthContextProvider = ({
  children,
  user,
  cookie,
}: {
  children: ReactNode;
  user: UserRecord;
  cookie: Cookie;
}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
      (window as any).cookie = cookie;
    }
    return auth.onIdTokenChanged(async (snap) => {
      if (!snap) {
        cookie.remove("__session");
        cookie.set("__session", "", { path: "/" });
        return;
      }
      const token = await snap.getIdToken();
      cookie.remove("__session");
      cookie.set("__session", token, { path: "/" });
    });
  }, [cookie]);

  return (
    <serverAuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        user,
        auth,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </serverAuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
  );
};
```

server-side root component

```js
const RootLayout = async ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  const { user } = await verifyAuthToken();
  if (!user) redirect("/login");

  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <ServerAuthContextProvider user={user}>
          {children}
        </ServerAuthContextProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
};
```

server-side token verification

```js
const verifyAuthToken = async () => {
  const auth = getAuth(firebaseAdmin);

  try {
    const session = cookies().get("__session");
    if (session?.value) {
      console.log("found token");
      const token = await auth.verifyIdToken(session.value);
      const { uid } = token;
      console.log("uid found: ", uid);
      const user = await auth.getUser(uid);
      return {
        auth,
        user,
      };
    }
  } catch (error: unknown) {
    if (typeof error === "string") {
      console.log("error", error);
      return {
        auth,
        error,
      };
    } else if (error instanceof Error) {
      console.log("error", error.message);

      return {
        auth,
        error: error.message,
      };
    }
  }
  return {
    auth,
  };
};
```

Comment: Did you get a workaround for this. Having the same issue

Comment: @taio unfortunately not - here is my repo, if you'd like to dig around https://github.com/MiroStW/shared-lists

Comment: I had mentioned using REST API only if the OP of that post had strict requirements to do so however I do not endorse it. To answer your question, you are setting user's ID Token in the cookies that is valid only for 1 hour. Instead, you must be using [session cookies](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions).  Have you checked them out already?

Comment: @Dharmaraj thanks a lot for your reply! You linked the doc for [Manage User Sessions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions) which is entirely about id token revocation. Did you mean to link to [Manage Session Cookies](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies)? I did not explore that yet, it looks fundamentally different, but I am very willing to try it out, if you say it does what I am looking for. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Yes, I accidentally copied the wrong link. Session cookies should work fine for SSR apps. I posted the same in short below.

Answer (score 3):

For SSR applications, you should use [session cookies](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies). Unlike ID Tokens, they do not expire in 1 hour and you can configure them to be active for up to 14 days. 
When a user logs in with Firebase client SDK, you can use `getIdToken()` once and pass to it an API that generates and sets a session cookie that can be read in subsequent requests.
This way you don't have keep the token updated using a listener.

Do make sure you log the user out from the client SDK either by settings [auth persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence) to `none` or explicitly logging out the user so in case you clear they cookie (using a logout API) there is no user on client side.

Comment: Hi @Dharmaraj, thanks a lot for your answer! It took a while, but I have now managed to implement a session cookie based auth. I am able to log in and persist for presumably 14 days. However I see some implications: 
1. I use firestore and apparently I can't simply use the http session cookie to authenticate firestore requests from the client (e.g. for onSnapshot listeners) 
2. to fix that I setPersistence to browserSessionPersistence to be able to authenticate client-side
3. to persist that for the full 14 days I added an authState listener that signs in with a custom token when needed

Comment: Of course I am not thrilled to have the 2nd layer of auth in the browser session storage. Is there a better way to use session cookies without the custom token authentification?